Cannot move out of `*r` which is behind a mutable reference
I am new to Rust. I am trying to understand the error of the test code:
fn main() {
    let mut v = String::from("hello,");
    let r = &mut v;

    match r {
       &mut value => value.push_str(" world!") 
    }
}

It raises the error:
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*r` which is behind a mutable reference
 --> src/main.rs:8:11
  |
8 |     match r {
  |           ^
9 |        &mut value => value.push_str(" world!") 
  |             -----
  |             |
  |             data moved here
  |             move occurs because `value` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |
help: consider removing the mutable borrow
  |
9 -        &mut value => value.push_str(" world!") 
9 +        value => value.push_str(" world!") 
  |

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `value` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:9:22
  |
9 |        &mut value => value.push_str(" world!") 
  |                      ^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
  |
help: consider changing this to be mutable
  |
9 |        &mut mut value => value.push_str(" world!") 
  |             +++

I understand that removing &mut from value can fix it, but I'm struggling to grasp why. My understanding is that (&|&&)mut? constitutes a reference pattern, which should dereference the pointers being matched and borrow them. So, in my case, the value of v should be borrowed by the pointer value, and neither v nor *r needs to be moved. However, the code appears to attempt to move out of *r, which seems contrary to my understanding. It feels like the behavior of a non-reference pattern: move or copy.
Can anyone help me understand why I'm encountering this error? I suspect I may have misunderstood something fundamental. Thank you for your assistance!

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78257433/5397009?

Since it's a match arm, &mut value is a pattern not a value / expression, in that context &mut does the opposite of what it does in an expression context (which is the point, patterns are rooted in applying expressions in reverse). So &mut value in a pattern context is a dereference.

So your match is an overly complicated way of writing let value = *r; value.push_str(" world!");, and since r is an &mut String, the dereference attempts to move the String out of the reference.

@Masklinn I understand &mut is a pattern. But I think this is a reference pattern rather than non-reference pattern. According to doc: reference-patterns, reference patterns dereference the pointers that are being matched and, thus, borrow them. I think it means that in the match arm, a new reference is created to borrow the String, so there is no need to move the String. If I remove & from &mut value, it will be a non-reference pattern, then it will follow the RFC. Am I wrong?

Yes, you're wrong, no new reference is created (unless you also use the ref keyword), as you can see by the equivalent match *int_reference {…} without a reference pattern in the example.

@Masklinn But based on my tests, it seems that both reference patterns and non-reference patterns try to move/copy value after dereference. I don't know if any RFCs change the behavior of the reference pattern to be the same as the non-reference pattern. My rust version is 1.73.0.

@cafce25 So, the reference pattern has the same behavior in the match arm as the non-reference pattern?

Yes, "these two matches on x: &i32 are equivalent" – as stated in the docs.

@cafce25 Thank you! But I don't understand why the RFC says the auto-dereference is for non-reference pattern. That's why I guessed the reference pattern should have a different behavior.

That applies when you neither dereference the variable nor use a reference pattern. But you do use a reference pattern. The RFC you linked basically states if you use neither (and hence it auto dereferences) then there is an implicit ref inserted before value in the pattern.

I think the "and, thus, borrow them" is very misleading (if not outright incorrect) in The Rust Reference as the result of the dereference might (as here) be a copy or move.

@eggyal I agree. I am misled by it. I thought it would create a new reference (borrow) to replace the old one which was dereferenced.
